# How do I add a custom unit of measure to Squants

Tags: scala, squants

I would like to add an additional unit of measure to the Squants library, specifically a volume of cm3 and volume flow of cm3_per_second and cm3_per_minute.

Can anyone give me some pointers on what classes, objects and typeclasses I need to implement?

Answer (score 0):

You can still define your own type (class) extends a given Squants type, in which you would override some computations. This library will not give you what you're looking for (at least not directly). It mainly provides type safety to avoid mixing computation of different quantities.